# Accessing Elements Inside iframe and body Tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, cross-browser

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script that modifies an attribute of an element with a specific ID, but I'm having some problems accessing it due to a nontraditional HTML hierarchy. Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<body>
...
    <iframe id="iframeID">
        <html>
        ...
            <body id="bodyID" attribute="value">
            ...
            </body>
        ...
        </html>
    </iframe>
...
</body>
```

Where `attribute` is the attribute that I'm attempting to modify.

At first, not realizing I was working with an `iframe` and a nested `body` tag, I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('bodyID').setAttribute("attribute","value")
```

While this worked fine in Firefox, Chrome tells me that I can't set the attribute of `null`, suggesting that it cannot find any elements with the id `bodyID`. How can I modify this attribute in a cross-browser friendly fashion?

Comment: Have you tried `window.frames`? (doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames)

Comment: @drderp While I think that would work, the code would contain unnecessary clutter compared to gdoron's solution.

Comment: gdoron posted his solution right after I posted mine;  I agree with you on this.

Comment: See my update regarding to `<body>` + the demo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to pull the document of the `<iframe>`:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument
.getElementById('bodyID').setAttribute("attribute","value");
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QfDyq/)

BTW, if you want to get the `<body>` node, you don't need to give id or something like that, simply:

```
document.body
```

In your case, it's the document of the `<iframe>`:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument.body.setAttribute("attribute","value");
```

A lot simpler... Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The best way, IMO, to do this is to listen for the `load` event fired by the iFrame, then look into the iFrame DOM as need. This guarantees that you'll have the iFrame DOM available when you need it and take a while shot.

```
$('#iframeID').on('load', function ()
{
  alert('loaded'); // iFrame successfully loaded
  var iFrameDoc = $('#iframeID')[0].contentDocument; // Get the iFrame document
  $('body', iFrameDoc).attr('attribute', 'new value'); // Get the 'body' in the iFrame document and set 'attribute' to 'new value'
});
```

Comment: Where is the `jQuery` tag? and read my comment regarding to `<body>`

Comment: @gdoron, add jQuery in your <head>. This will not work if the iFrame and the iFrame container have a different domain due to cross-domain policy.

Comment: Not sure what you meant to say regarding to jQuery. and your answer has the same problem with cross-domain policy.