# Accessing DOM elements inside nested HTML and BODY tags

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

As answered by a commenter, this is is not possible without access to the external site due to a cross domain security policy.

```
IframeModify.js:8 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://MYDOMAIN" from accessing a frame with origin "https://EXTERNALDOMAIN". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I am writing a web application in PHP and javascript. The web page pulls in an IFrame from a third-party source. We have no control over the content within the iframe and cannot modify it at all.

NOTE: I am unable to use JQUERY and the solution here did not work for me so please do not mark as duplicate: [Accessing Elements Inside iframe and body Tags with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277766/accessing-elements-inside-iframe-and-body-tags-with-javascript)

I am simply trying to remove some HTML elements that appear in that IFrame.

I have a piece of javascript that is called when the iframe loads and attempts to get those elements by class name. The script runs AFTER the IFrame is loaded so I know that isn't the problem. I have tested it with a long timer as well, just to make absolutely sure timing isnt the issue with loading the elements before they are accessible.

I think the issue is because the IFrame includes its own HTML and BODY tags.

So, when I try to use document.getElementsByClassName("help-url") it is only able to access elements in the first HTML tag. I am sure of this because I tested it and was able to access elements in the OUTER HTML tag, but x.length returned zero elements when trying to access anything within the nested HTML tag.

How can I access the nested elements within that iframe?

Here is the basic structure of the nested HTML and Body tags.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<!-- some of my content -->
<iframe onload="rmvLink()"> <!-- this is the external iframe -->
    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript, including the timer, so we know that it isnt a timing issue.

```
function rmvLink() {

  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {
    alert('loaded');
    setTimeout(rmv, 3000);
  }

function rmv() {
    var duoIframeLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("help-url");
    alert(duoIframeLinks.length); //returns 0
}
```

Comment: "This creates a messy DOM with nested HTML tags." — No, it doesn't. It creates multiple DOMs with links between each other.

Comment: Hi Quentin can you please unmark this as a duplicate? The solution suggested does not work.

Comment: Re edit. You said "THE DUPLICATE SOLUTIONS DO NOT WORK ", the answer to the duplicate question says: "If you don't have control over the framed site, you cannot circumvent the cross-domain policy" — That **isn't a solution** it is a statement that what you want is **impossible**.

Comment: … and the error you are getting appears to be when you run the **non-working** code that the duplicate question is asking about.